# generalized word problem

Tags: gr.group-theory

If $H$ is a finitely generated subgroup of $G$ and if $H$ given by say a finite set
of words which generate it, then the generalized word problem for $H$ in $G$
is the problem of deciding for an arbitrary word $w$ in $G$ whether or not $w$
lies in the subgroup $H$.

In "Computable algebra and group embeddings", it is shown that one can solve the generalized word
problem for finitely generated, abelian-by-nilpotent groups. Is  this result generalized to the finitely generated abelian by polycyclic groups?

Comment: Context: $G$ is a group with a given finite generating family (so that "words" makes sense). To say that the generalized word problem is solvable in some class $C$ of f.g. groups means that for every $G\in C$ and every finite generating family (a given one is enough), and every f.g. subgroup $H\subset G$ given by a finite generating set of words, the generalized word problem for $(G,H)$ is solvable (I still have a doubt whether the algorithm should be uniform in $H$, which would sound a more natural assumption).

Comment: I am struggling to understand "finitely generated abelian by polycyclic groups". You must surely be aware that, for classes A and B of groups "A by B groups" can have one of two different meanings, so could you say exacly what you mean?

Comment: According to a survey article by C.F. Miller written in about 1989, this is unknown. Of course it is possible that there has been further progrss since then.

Comment: @DerekHolt Very likely it means abelian kernel, polycyclic quotient as it's an interesting class of groups (according to the same convention kernel-by-quotient, a polycyclic-by-abelian f.g. group is f.g., hence polycyclic, so it would be stupid to refer to this class)

Comment: by an abelian by polycyclic group G, I  mean a group with an abelian normal subgroup N such that  G/N is polycyclic

Comment: @YCor Yes, it is very often (but not always) the case that when there are two or more possible interpretations of a mathemtical statement, that only one of them makes much sense, but I still prefer not to have to spend possibly several minutes figuring out which one that is!

Comment: On the other hand I mentioned two possible intrepretations of "group with solvable generalized word problem", which are both nontrivial and would require some clarification by the OP (anyway both questions are natural), and probably have a positive answer (although abelian-by-polycylic is often much harder than abelian-by-nilpotent).